# Build a Cross Compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++, mips

I'm trying to compile a c++ file and generate an asm or s file to be disassembled and run in PSIM. Whenever I try to do this I get errors. I am attempting to compile to mipsI-linux. I think I've determined that my cross compiler that was given to me is not working correctly for some reason. Can anyone give me some help building a new cross compiler that will generate the correct instruction format? I'm working on a MAC.

Comment: What compiler are you using for c#?

Comment: C# is not C++. You need to tag your question correctly and make sure your question is asking the correct thing. What language are you using - C++ or C#?

Comment: C++, sorry, new to this world

Comment: Googling for `building gcc cross compiler mips` gives bunch of hits. I used Google in past to build PPC cross compiler on Linux/x86. On Mac I do not expect it to be much different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at [crosstool-NG](http://ymorin.is-a-geek.org/projects/crosstool) (based on [crosstool](http://kegel.com/crosstool/)) which seems to make building a cross-compiler toolchain relatively easy.

Answer (score 3):

A great place to start is [Cross Linux-From-Scatch](http://trac.cross-lfs.org/).  The first step it walks you through is building a cross-compiler with all of its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a number of approaches and found that using [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) was the simplest and most reliable approach. Just download Buildroot, uncompress, cd to the top-level directory and run `make-menuconfig`. Set the options such as what target machine you need the cross compiler for, and run `make`.

The make takes 15-20 mins and needs an active internet connection as all sources are downloaded from online archives and built. After the build you get: a cross compiler toolchain (gcc,as,ld etc, and glibc or ulibc whichever you choose in the options). After `make`, the binaries (named < arch >-linux-gcc, < arch >-linux-as etc) are located at

`<buildroot-top-directory>/output/host/usr/bin.`

Add this location to your `PATH` variable (for linux users) and that's it.

Edit: Sorry, I noticed just now that the question is for MAC. Buildroot may not be officially supported for MAC.